# Specification pattern or entity / value object validation

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, validation, business-rules

I m trying to understand the core concepts of DDD and I m having some troubles dealing with validations.

In fact, I m actually wondering where and when should I use specification pattern instead of Entity / ValueObject validations.

Moreover, I m trying to find a way to avoid this kind of validation in my Application service :

```
if(Email.isValid(emailString)){
  User usr = new User(emailString);
}
```

In fact, what could happen if I have multiple validation like 10 - 20 on certain field ? I don't neither want to throw multiple exceptions, which are, in my sense, dedicated to critical errors.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Throws Hey,That'sNotEmailException
Email email = new Email(emailString);
User user = new User(email);
```

Alternative spelling

```
// Throws Hey,That'sNotEmailException
Email email = Email.from(emailString);
User user = new User(email);
```

Using explicit value types is great for supporting validation.

Comment: I've seen therefore that it's not a bad practice to inject a defined Specification (https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core/blob/master/src/main/java/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo/Delivery.java#L63) . What do you think about that ? It seems weird to be to inject some specs inside of VO or entities.. Like it doesn't fit what they should do...